# Vue 3: [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component

Tags: vuejs3

In Vue 3, when I register a component to use, I use the following in my .js file:

```js
import blogpost from '../../../blogpost.vue'
app.use(blogpost);
```

I create a simple component, i.e. `BlogPost.vue`.

```
<!-- BlogPost.vue -->
<template>
    <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'BlogPost',
        props: ['title']
    }
</script>
```

In my html file, I call the following:

```
<div id="app">
    <blogpost title = 'test'/>
</div>
```

When I run the app, I get the following:

> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?fea0:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve
> component: blogpost.
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

It's like Vue can't render the component. I am using webpack to compile, so if I put the wrong location in, it errors out. So the location is right, I guess?

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you have solved this, anyway, here is the answer. Use `app.component()` to globally register a component (look [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#global-registration)).